# Jenkins tag name is invalid

Tags: scala, jenkins

Has anyone seen the following exception from Jenkins?

```
FATAL: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidTagNameException: tag name jenkins-Push Notifications API (Master)-3 is invalid
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidTagNameException: tag name jenkins-Push Notifications API (Master)-3 is invalid
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.JGitAPIImpl.tag(JGitAPIImpl.java:179)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.tag(GitAPI.java:220)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$4.invoke(GitSCM.java:1239)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$4.invoke(GitSCM.java:1196)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:865)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:838)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1196)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1353)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:689)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:594)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1567)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidTagNameException: tag name jenkins-Push Notifications API (Master)-3 is invalid
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.TagCommand.processOptions(TagCommand.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.TagCommand.call(TagCommand.java:112)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.JGitAPIImpl.tag(JGitAPIImpl.java:175)
    ... 14 more
```

This is a Scala project and we are using SBT 12.1 to build it. My googling has only returned issues with older versions of Jenkins which I am past. We have 1.506.

We have a ton of other projects building just fine and some of them are also Scala.

Comment: I got this error building a Java project. I'm not sure why this would suddenly crop up, but I was able to work around it by going into the Advanced... config settings for the Source Code Management section of the build config and checking "Skip Internal Tag". Hopefully that helps you too.

Comment: @NathanSmith Great success! If you submit that as an answer instead of a comment, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this error building a Java project. I'm not sure why this would suddenly crop up, but I was able to work around it by doing the following:

Go to the **Advanced...** config settings for the **Source Code Management** section of the build config and check "Skip Internal Tag".

(upgraded from comment)